# How to pass data extension external key into FUEL SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, python

I need to access data extensions using FUEL SDK and am following the code found here (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extensions/data-extension-retrieve.html#pythonpost) but **how do I specify which data extension I need to be pulling via the external keys in the above code?**

I successfully pulled the data extension and get the message "" but not sure what is inside this or which extension it pulled.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that be a huge help for work.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work on the same page

```
dataextension.search_filter = {'Property' : 'CustomerKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : 'MyDataExtension'}
```

CustomerKey is the External Key here

Comment: It worked maneesh!